# .htaccess. Redirect with Rewrite Condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How to make redirect from 
site.com/**ru**/blablabla to
site.com/blablabla
??

And one more if on link site.com/en/blablabla server return 404, 
then I need redirect to site.com/blablabla

my .htaccess:

```
    ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

######### MY RULES #########
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/ru\/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ /%1
```

Comment: Is it specific to "**ru**" or any word?
Same thing for "en" too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you remove all the lines under `######### MY RULES #########`
 line and put this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|ru)/(.*)$ /$2 [R,L]
```

This will take care of both /ru/foo and /en/foo URLs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
Add `RewriteEngine on` at the top of the .htaccess file

---

Try this rule: for **ru** and **404**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/ru\/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ /%1
```

in that case (English version) i can suggest you to check HTTP_REFERER in errordocument (in above case its error404.php)... and redirect the request to respective page... (in your case its /blablabla)

Hope you got my point.. :)

Comment: My site is multilanguage. Now http://f1u.org/ - russian, http://f1u.org/en - english. Yesterday russian version was on http://f1u.org/ru. So I want to redirect all urls http://f1u.org/ru/* to http://f1u.org/*

Comment: Another problem: Google indexed this page: http://f1u.org/en/its-interesting/166-cricri, but it's no more exists. I want to do redirect to the same russian page http://f1u.org/its-interesting/166-cricri if server returns 404 .So I need some rule which will redirect all 404 english links to russian ones.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file.
because i tried same rule on my domain and its working fine...